# SSIS Task "Transfer SQL Server Objects" is NOT copying Synonyms to new DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am using SSIS Task "Transfer SQL Server Objects" to clone database structures on-demand onto our TEST server version SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 (10.50.6220).

However, it is NOT transferring/copying SYNONYM objects across to new DB.

Any help or suggestion on how to fix this or even workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the failure to copy them is by design. See here for the list of DB objects that that type of task can move (synonyms isn't on the list):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142159(v=sql.110).aspx

For a workaround, I'd suggest just scripting the CREATE statements in a SQL task after the move of everything else completes.

Good luck!

Comment: That's right I get that synonyms are not on the list. But they are still valid objects and our databases have synonyms and stored procedure and functions are consuming those synonyms. 

Being not able to bring these synonyms, would mean all these SPs & UDF etc. become invalid. Now all I looking to find is a simple way to script and automate synonyms  to complete the object transfer task.

Comment: Guys can I request you to please upvote the question, I may get some suitable answer to my little problem..